# Are Mirror Servers Other Than Default Safe To Use For Updates?

Tags: server, mirrors

My default mirror server was very slow and so I decided to switch to another server to speed up the updating process. However, because there are so many of these servers to choose from -- most of which are hosted on sites I never knew about -- one question keeps bugging me about switching from the default one: Is it generally safe to do that?

All kind feedback is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is generally safe.

Apt has the packages signed, and verifies those signatures.

Ubuntu is based off Debian, who designed the package system. If you want to read more about their package signing, you can do so at https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt.

I suppose a mirror could not tell you about updates when they are released, but you would likely notice that you were getting no updates after a while.